# How to find unused / unaccessed objects in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, audit

Is there a way to find unused objects ( Tables, Views etc ) within datasets in BigQuery or objects less frequently accessed ( like we can run audits in Oracle to find out the same )

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a BigQuery script that does the following:

- List and store in a temporary table ALL the tables, in ALL the datasets in the project, modified before a reference date (set at the beginning as a variable `reference_date`). This temporary table contains all the "old" tables we want to check if they are used by someone in the next step

  ```
  DECLARE reference_date STRING;
  SET reference_date = '2023-01-01';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (
    SELECT CONCAT("CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE OLD_TABLES AS ", STRING_AGG(
      CONCAT(CONCAT("SELECT table_catalog,table_schema,table_name FROM ", schema_name, ".INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS "),
      FORMAT("WHERE DATE(last_modified_time) < '%s' \n", reference_date)),  
      "UNION ALL \n"
    ))
    FROM `region-eu`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
  );
  ```
- Join the list of all the tables (from the previous step) with a list of queried tables available in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS` view, which contains the query job history of the past 180 days and can be used to obtain a list of recently used tables

  ```
  WITH TABLE_LIST AS (
    SELECT 
      OLD_TABLES.table_catalog,
      OLD_TABLES.table_schema,
      OLD_TABLES.table_name,
      QUERIES.table_id,
    FROM OLD_TABLES
    LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT
        jobs.project_id, 
        ref.dataset_id,
        ref.table_id,
      FROM `region-eu`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS as jobs, UNNEST(referenced_tables) as ref
      WHERE ref.project_id = jobs.project_id
    ) QUERIES
    ON 
      OLD_TABLES.table_name = QUERIES.table_id
      AND OLD_TABLES.table_schema = QUERIES.dataset_id
  )
  ```
- **Extract only the name of the tables (with also dataset reference) which have as the last update time a date older than `reference_date` and are NOT used in the last 180 days as reported by `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS` view**

  ```
  SELECT * EXCEPT(table_id) 
  FROM TABLE_LIST
  WHERE table_id IS NULL
  ```

PS: this script can identify the unused tables only in the project where the script is running

Answer (score 0):

Just like you can run audits in Oracle, you can enable [StackDriver logging on BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring) and run audits from StackDriver.

If you'd also like to use BigQuery syntax to query StackDriver logging, you can [export StackDriver logging to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Appreciate it v.much. Do any of these above 2 options involve me incurring additional costs ?

Comment: StackDriver logging has its own pricing model: https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/pricing. If you export log back to BigQuery, BigQuery storage and query cost applies as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can take stackdriver loggings into BigQuery again and run the Audit queries against that table
2. Create Stackdriver Monitoring on the same using custom metrics.

Both of these [incur costs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing). 
However, BigQuery automatically lowers  cost on the data stored in tables or in partitions that have not been modified in the last 90 days.

Answer (score 0):

we can write a script to find the unused bq table through the logs file. This script works in a manner to find a bq tables list on which query has been done for the last (Number of days).

with obtained bq table list will compare with a final table list which contains a total list of tables.